# IUPAC Nomenclature of the organic compound(See Picture)

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

[image: Please justify the solution]

Question:IUPAC nomenclature of the given organic compound
Given answer is Option 4

Comment: All suggested answers (1)–(4) are wrong. But anyway, what is [_your_ question](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3120/7951)?

Comment: Question : IUPAC name of this compound

Answer (score 5):

In the compound that is given in the question, only the amine can be expressed as a suffix; therefore, the principal characteristic group can only be the amine. The compound has also only one parent structure; therefore, there is no question about which chain or ring is the senior parent structure. Any further substituents are expressed as prefix. Therefore, the compound is a **chlorocyclohexenamine.** The only remaining question is about the correct numbering of locants.

The most important simplified criteria for the numbering in such cases are:

1. lower locants for the principal characteristic group that is expressed as suffix
2. lower locants for multiple bonds
3. lower locants for prefixes
4. lower locants for substituents cited first as a prefix in the name

The corresponding actual wording in the current version of *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069)* reads as follows:

> **P-14.4** NUMBERING
>
> When several structural features appear in cyclic and acyclic compounds, low locants are assigned to them in the following decreasing order of seniority:
>
> (…)
>
> (c) principal characteristic groups and free valences (suffixes);
>
> (…)
>
> (e) saturation/unsaturation:
>
> (i) low locants are given to hydro/dehydro prefixes (…) and ‘ene’ and ‘yne’ endings;
>
> (ii) low locants are given first to multiple bonds as a set and then to double bonds (…);
>
> (f) detachable alphabetized prefixes, all considered together in a series of increasing numerical order;
>
> (g) lowest locants for the substituent cited first as a prefix in the name;
>
> (…)

The lowest locant is assigned first to the principal characteristic group according to rule (c), i.e. 1-amine.

Next, a low locant is assgined to the double bond according to Rule (e). Therefore, the name of the structure without further substituents is cyclohex-3-en-1-amine.

Now the locant for the chloro substituent can only get the number 5.

Therefore, the complete name for the compound that is given in the question is **5-chlorocyclohex-3-en-1-amine.**

[image: 5-chlorocyclohex-3-en-1-amine]